# Defined two meteor local collections and helpers exactly the same. One helper works. The other doesn't

Tags: meteor

I create these two local collections (the code is actually written one after the other exactly like below):

```
ShoppingCartCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);
CurrentPricesCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);
```

Inside `Template.myTemplate.rendered` I add some initial info into these collections (again, code is one after the other):

```
ShoppingCartCollection.insert({"sqft" : "not yet entered"});
CurrentPricesCollection.insert({"hdrPhotos" : 100});
```

I've got these two global helpers in `helpers.js` (defined one after the other)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("shoppingCart", function() {
  return ShoppingCartCollection.findOne();
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("currentPrice", function() {
  return CurrentPricesCollection.findOne();
});
```

When I load the page I immediately run these commands in the console:

```
> ShoppingCartCollection.findOne();

Object {sqft: "not yet entered", _id: "xcNmqJvMqqD5j7wwn"}

> CurrentPricesCollection.findOne();

Object {hdrPhotos: 100, _id: "LP38E3MZgzuYjvSec"}
```

In my template I use these helpers, but...

```
{{currentPrice.hdrPhotos}} //displays nothing

{{shoppingCart.sqft}} //displays "not yet entered"
```

How... what... ? How can this be? Are there some kind of gotchas that I could be missing? Some kind of dependency or load order that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are those two helper calls also next to each other?

Comment: Yup. Side by side. Same template.

Comment: Works fine here, will post exact files.

Comment: reversed order of templates, changed nothing.

Comment: Grrrr... I restarted my meteor server. Same thing. I'll try to do a reset.

Comment: If you are still having problems after comparing my code to yours and taking action on any obvious differences, you should probably edit your question and add:  (1) result of meteor --version; (2) actual .html file or templates code used

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is working fine here.

Suggest comparing this code to the exact details of what you are doing.  Also, look
for other problems, typos, etc.

Below is the exact test procedure I used:

From nothing, at the linux console:

`meteor create sodebug`

Note that this will produce files for a "hello world" type program.

Check the version:

```
meteor --version
Release 0.8.1.1
```

Edit sodebug/sodebug.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // code autogenerated by meteor create
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to sodebug.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input': function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
  // add your code here
    ShoppingCartCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);
    CurrentPricesCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);

    ShoppingCartCollection.insert({"sqft" : "not yet entered"});
    CurrentPricesCollection.insert({"hdrPhotos" : 100}); 
    Handlebars.registerHelper("shoppingCart", function() {
    return ShoppingCartCollection.findOne();
    });

    Handlebars.registerHelper("currentPrice", function() {
    return CurrentPricesCollection.findOne();
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Edit sodebug.html:

```
<head>
  <title>sodebug</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
  {{> T1 }}
  {{> T2 }} 
</body>

<template name="T1">
<p>
{{shoppingCart.sqft}}
</p>
</template>
<template name="T2">
<p>
{{currentPrice.hdrPhotos}}
</p>
</template>
<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

Run: `meteor run`

Manual tests:

Fire up chromium browser at localhost:3000

Check web browser console for collections data.  PASS

Check web browser screen for templates data.  PASS

Reorder templates in `sodebug.html` file, check web browser screen. PASS

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's going on. `helpers.js` inside my `client` folder is different from my `helpers.js` inside the hidden `.meteor` folder. The problem though is that if I delete the `helpers.js` inside the hidden folder and then do `meteor rebuild-all` it continues to rebuild the old, out-of-sync `helpers.js` inside the hidden folder. This old version inside `.meteor` doesn't include the global helpers I defined in the OP. Meteor 0.8.1.3. But how does it even know to rebuild the old version??? Where are the instructions to rebuild the old version even coming from?

Comment: Uhhh... I closed my text editor (Sublime) to make sure that it wasn't locking down any files. I did another rebuild and this time everything seems to be back to normal. Still does not explain how Meteor was finding the info to rebuild an old version of `helpers.js` though.